# Find the probability that two samples of F unique items taken from a population of N unique items has at least one common item

Tags: combinatorics

What is the probability that two samples of F unique items taken from a population of N unique items has at least one common item?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=hypergeometric+distribution.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for bringing this up. I totally forgot about the hypergeometric distribution. The function P is P=1-hypergeom where the total successes input to the hypergeometric distribution is 0.

Answer (score 1):

The formula for the probability, $P$,  that 2 people will randomly choose at least one of the same unique items when they get to choose $F$ total unique items from a list or population of $N$ unique items is

$P=1-\frac{(N-F)!^2}{N!(N-2F)!}$.

To understand this, consider that there are $C=\frac{N!}{F!(N-F)!}$ unique ways to arrange $F$ items from a selection of $N$ total items. After person 1 chooses $F$ items, there are $N-F$ items that person 1 did not choose. Now, for person 2 to choose $F$ items that person 1 didn’t choose, there are $D=\frac{(N-F)!}{F!(N-2F)!}$ combinations to choose from. So, from the $C$ total combinations, $C-D$ contain at least one the items that person 1 chose.

Finally, the percentage that contain at least one of the items that person 1 chose is

$P=\frac{C-D}{C}=1-\frac{(N-F)!^2}{N!(N-2F)!}$.

Here's a MATLAB code that verifies this answer through brute force:

clc

clear all

N=34;F=5;HowFew=2; HowMany=factorial(N)/(factorial(F)*factorial(N-F));

for i=1:HowFew

```
clear A Totcount B
```

A=randperm(N,F);

Totcount=zeros(HowMany,1);

B=zeros(HowMany,F);

for j=1:HowMany

```
   B(j,:)=randperm(N,F);

   for k=1:F

      if (sum(ismember(B(j,:),A(k)))>=1)

      Totcount(j)=1;

      end

   end
```

end

K(i)=length(find(Totcount==1))/length(Totcount);

end

Sim=mean(K); %The simulation percent

Theory=1-factorial(N-F)^2/(factorial(N)*factorial(N-2*F)); %The theory percent